# regex to replace any word with two capital letters

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to replace any word which contains two capital letters .

here is my string

```
jennie-garth-jennie-garth-inner-city-arts-gala-october-17-2012-If9aSpTW
jennie-garth-jennie-garth3892-H9rDcbY
```

i want to replace -If9aSpTW with -

These `-If9aSpTW` varies so I can't use `str_replace`. I can identify with only  two capital letter in one word. These words are at the end, but these types of words are appearing for 20% of total database values so I can't replace all last words.

Comment: i am not getting how to do.

Comment: Have you considered `explode("-", $val)` and then `implode` leaving out the last chunk? Or just `substr($s, 0, strrpos( $s, '-'));`. It might be enough. You mentioned that these appear at the end of the string, what makes them specific? More than one capital letter?

Comment: Ok, try `$result = preg_replace('/-(?:[^-]*[A-Z]){2,}[^-]*$/', '', $str);`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LIhzBQ/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes. i cant delete all last letter blindly as these types of data are only 20% of total rows. so i have to delete only words where two capital letters are there

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew trying.........

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew plz give it in answer it works. thanks. please explain little how it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `str_replace` is context unaware, nor can you use `substr` since you need to check for 2 uppercase letters in the last non-hyphen chunk of the text. So you really have to stick to `preg_replace` regex based replacement.

You may use the following regex:

```
preg_replace('/-(?:[^-]*[A-Z]){2,}[^-]*$/', '', $str);
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LIhzBQ/1).

The pattern matches:

- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?:[^-]*[A-Z]){2,}` - 2 or more occurrences (due to `{2,}` limiting quantifier) of a sequence of:

  - `[^-]*`
  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase
- `[^-]*` - zero or more chars other than `-`
- `$` - end of string

[PHP](https://ideone.com/BjiEEU):

```
$str = 'jennie-garth-jennie-garth-inner-city-arts-gala-october-17-2012-If9aSpTWe';
echo preg_replace('/-(?:[^-]*[A-Z]){2,}[^-]*$/', '', $str);
```

Comment: Not sure IDEONE is working correctly now, at least it shows the correct result.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew love u